# Oauth2 workflow of creating and returning access tokens (using Django)

Tags: django, oauth-2.0, django-authentication

After reading a lot about `Oauth2.0`, I am still confused regarding following points:

1. When to create access token? When a user tries to log in or when a user tries to register? Is this token to be sent in HTTP response after logging in?
2. The client has to store access token somewhere so that it can be sent in every HTTP request by the client. Where should it store it?

Note: I am not doing any third party authentication, just authentication for my own app. I am using Django as the web framework, Django-tastypie for REST API and Django-oauth-provider for Oauth. I followed [this excellent tutorial](http://ianalexandr.com/blog/building-a-true-oauth-20-api-with-django-and-tasty-pie.html) but still have certain doubts. It will be appreciated if the answer is given in the context of these frameworks.